# What causes these diamonds in water droplets on a screen?

Tags: visible-light, water, refraction

It was raining yesterday and the screen of my iPad ended up covered in varying sized water droplets.

[image]

As you can see, the smallest water droplets look transparent, and then as the size increases the grid of pixels appears. Then, at a very specific size, the grid disappears and a diamond with much more solid colour appears.

Not visible in the photo is that droplets larger than the diamond ones show a grid again. It is only a fairly specific size of droplet which forms the solid diamond. In addition, the diamond was visible both on camera and directly - this is not a Moiré pattern.

Why is this diamond visible in the droplet, and why is it only in a very specific size of droplet?

Answer (score 1):

The droplets on your screen act as plano-convex lenses.

[image]

As depicted in the schematic diagram above, the focal length $f$ is the distance between the lens and it's focal point. $f$ depends on the radius of curvature of the lens: A higher radius of curvature results in a larger $f$.

The radius of curvature decreases for smaller droplets due to surface tension (i.e. the bigger the droplet, the "flatter" it is).

The pixels of your screen have a fixed distance $d$ to the droplets (the thickness of your screen's glass). Now if we compare a droplet for which $d>f$ with a droplet for which $d<f$, we notice that the image has to be flipped (cf. with the diagram).

If, however, $d \approx f$, the light of the single pixels is "spread" almost over the whole lens, resulting in the blurry spots you see in the center of the diamond-shaped images.
The diamond shape consists, if you look closely, of the black horizontal lines connecting to the black vertical lines due to distortion of the image. For a drop with perfect size, $d = f$, the diamond shape sould not be visible, because in this case the blurry spot would cover the whole image.

**Addendum**:

The above also explains why very small and very large droplets appear transparent: For $d \ll f$, it is almost as if there is no lens. For $d \approx 2f$, the image is just flipped, but not magnified.

Also, the color of the blurry spot is coming from the fact that each pixel consists of three single-coloured subpixels.